ngx-mat-intl-tel-input not working properly in Angular 17
I am using Angular 17,
with following Versions/Details
Angular CLI: 17.3.8
Node: 18.20.2
Package Manager: npm 10.5.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 17.3.12

I want to import library ngx-intl-tel-input to validate phone number with country Code.
I just checked following both:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-intl-tel-input
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-intl-tel-input-gg
package.json file packages:
"google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.38",
"intl-tel-input": "^17.0.3",
"ngx-intl-tel-input": "^3.2.0",

angular.json File changes:
"styles": [
    "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
    "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js",
]

And also import module in app-component
I can see a text box with country flag and I can enter phone number.
However, when I click on country flag the drop down does not open

did you manage to fix this issue?

I think you are missing provideAnimations which needs to be added to the providers array of bootstrapApplication.
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...

...
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    ...
    provideAnimations(),
    ...
  ]
});


I tried but it didn't work

@KishanBhola Could you share a stackblitz or github repo where the issue happens?
